# Keeping WebRTC video stream active while navigating through site

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm looking for the best way to keep a WebRTC video stream + the stream controls (hang up, mute etc.) loaded and active, even if the user navigates to another subpage through the navigation menu.
I thought of the following way, however I don't know if this is the most practical one or if there's a better solution to this nowadays: I'd simply make a wrapper with the navigation menu and put an iFrame where currently the content is. The video stream itself would go in the menu bar itself (it's a sidebar which is wide enough to do something like this), when the user clicks on a menu item, the iFrame src is replaced with the new URL.
Is this the right way to do this? If so however, since I haven't used iFrames that much so far, I have a few more concerns:

1. Are there any drawbacks as for browser features when using iFrame? For example, I know that Chrome asks you to put several features into the `allow` attribute of the iFrame, for example when using the camera, microphone or location of the user. Is there anything I absolutely cannot do in iFrames?
2. Do iFrames share the (PHP) session and cookies with the "main" wrapper, or are those separate sessions?
3. And probably my biggest concern: How could the JavaScript codes of the wrapper and the iFrames communicate with each other? For example, how could I send a hangup-signal to the video stream in the wrapper from within the iFrame?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iframes could work.

> Are there any drawbacks as for browser features when using iFrame?

The main issue is that you don't really get control over the presentation of the page while that iframe loads.  Users may see a brief moment of solid white, for example, while the previous page is torn down and replaced.

> Is there anything I absolutely cannot do in iFrames?

Iframes are pretty flexible.  Just keep in mind that they have their own JavaScript context so there is some extra code you need to write to shuffle data back and forth.

> Do iFrames share the (PHP) session and cookies with the "main" wrapper

Yes

> How could the JavaScript codes of the wrapper and the iFrames communicate with each other?

You can actually access the Document object for the iframe from the outer iframe.  (Assuming they're on the same origin, of course.)

```
const iframe = document.querySlector('iframe');
iframe.contentDocument.querySelector('body').whateveryouwant
```

Probably the best way though is to use the postMessage API.  This allows you send data back and forth as-needed, in a nice isolated way.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll probably indeed use iFrames and postMessage then.